# Faster way then mine to populate a vector with unique integers except two values ? C++

Tags: c++, optimization, random, vector

I can´t post my all program here, just snippets. Will answer any question.

**What I have**:

1) I have a vector with 20 ID´s, like this [0,1,2,3,4,5,6...19].

2) I pick two ID´s, for example number 3 and number 6.

**What I need**:

1) Generate a vector of size N-1, where the N=5. This vector should not contain number 3 and number 6, only the remaining ID´s, and do not repeat them.
For example: new vector = [7,2,19,4]. Yes, only 4 items because the 5th is the number 3 or number 6, they will play with this new created groups, so 1+4 =5(N).

**My problem**:

1) I need to do this like 1 millions times. It is very slow. I believe that this part of code is the most heavy, because I deleted that part and the program runs really fast without it.

**My question**:

1) Below is my code, the *do while* loop, can I somehow optimize it ? maybe I need to use another structure or smarter method to generate this ?

**Code**:

```
for (int i = 0; i < _iterations; i++)
    {
        players.clear();
        int y = 0;
        do{
            // _pop_size = 20
            int rand_i = static_cast<int>(rand_double(0, _pop_size));
            if (rand_i != 3 && rand_i != 6){
             // verify if the ID already exists in vector
                if (std::find(players.begin(), players.end(), rand_i) == players.end()){
                    players.push_back(rand_i);
                    ++y;
                }
            }
          } while (y < _group_size - 1);
   // ...
   // ...
   // ...
   // ...
```

**rand_double() function**:

```
    double rand_double(int min, int max) const
{
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 mt(rd());
    std::uniform_real_distribution<double> dist(min, max);

    return dist(mt);
}
```

Comment: " I need to do this like 1 millions times."  Q: *WHAT* do you "need to do like millions of times"?  More specifically *WHAT EXACTLY CAN YOU TAKE OUT OF A LOOP*???  Simply analyze your logic, find the stuff you don't need to repeat, and take it out of the loop.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ This would get shot down very quickly there. Don't migrate crap.

Comment: @Mast  I shot that out anyways.

Comment: The rand_double function: you do not have to keep reseeding the generator every time. Hoist everything out of the function except for `return dist(mt);` and toss it up in global space so it is initialized once. Then take a look at std::bind because you can `auto rand_double = std::bind ( dist, mt);` and ditch the function entirely.

Comment: Next, why create random doubles and then cast them to int? Why not use [std::uniform_int_distribution](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution) in the first place?

Comment: @paulsm4 I am simulating a game called Ultimatum Game, very similar to Public Goods Game. I need to execute that do while loop almost million times because I need average values after many games. I am making a study. I cant take anything from the loop, I need new groups every time. There is nothing to take out, at least I cant find it.

Comment: You are going to spend a lot of time doing linear searches through that vector. Why not use a [std::set](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set)? Much faster look up.

Comment: @user4581301 my random function returns a double and I need an integer, to use later as an index for the vector. But from the web page you gave me, std::uniform_int_distribution will give me sometimes same integers, I would be wasting time by getting same integers, I need more random. But I will give it a shot. thanks

Comment: A similar proportion of the doubles will truncate to the same integer when you do the cast, so you're damned if you do, damned if you don't.

Comment: `if (rand_i != 3 && rand_i 6)` the `rand_i 6` part should be giving you grief.

Comment: @user4581301good point !

Comment: @user4581301 haha. my mistake, the code has this line: if (rand_i != two_players[0] && rand_i != two_players[1]). I just used 3 and 6 for the example.

Comment: @user4581301 I did like you said, I modified the random function. The seed is global and I use uniform_int_destribution. My program runs 3x times faster now !

Comment: Replace the vector with a set and you should see another good increase. If you don't want a set later, copy the set contents into a vector after the loops done

Comment: @user4581301: A vector of only 20 elements is short enough that just doing one random shuffle of it and taking the first 5 elements might be best.  That would mean you only need one random number per list, and that you don't need to hash each member to check it.  (If the ID numbers are all small, a set implemented as an array of `bool`, rather than a hash, would be fast, too.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is part gathering up the comments and part to prove a point.

The objective is to get as much as possible out of the processing loop. The first to die is the repeated re-initialization of the random number generator. A random number generator should be set up once and then used repeatedly, so re-init is a bad idea. Good riddance.

The next is to find a faster way to reject already known elements. The current approach uses a linear search through an unsorted vector. Insertion is quick because push_back only really slows down if resizing, but the more items in the vector the longer the worst case search time. A std:: set is an ordered list with very fast look-up, and somewhat slow insert. If the lists are short, stick with vector. If the lists are long (_group_size > 100), go with the set.

Here is an example with long lists:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <vector>
#include <random>
#include <functional>
#include <chrono>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std::chrono; // I know, but the lines were ridiculously long

// remove random number generator init from processing loop.
std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 mt(rd());
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(0, 1000000);
// replace function with a bind.
auto rand_int = std::bind(dist, mt);

// test function
int main()
{
    int y;
    int _group_size = 10000; // loop 10000 times
    std::set<int> tempplayers;
    std::vector<int> players;


    auto start = high_resolution_clock::now(); // get start time
    // with vector
    do
    {
        // _pop_size = 20
        int rand_i = rand_int();
        if (rand_i != 3 && rand_i != 6)
        { //using vector: Linear search.
            if (std::find(players.begin(), players.end(), rand_i) == players.end())
            {
                players.push_back(rand_i);
                ++y;
            } // verify if the ID already exists in vector
        }
    } while (y < _group_size - 1);
    auto t1 = duration_cast<nanoseconds>(high_resolution_clock::now() - start).count();
    // Calculate elapsed time

    std::cout << "Time (ns) with vector: " << t1 << std::endl;

    // reset
    players.clear();
    y = 0;

    // run again with a set instead of a vector
    start = high_resolution_clock::now();
    do
    {
        // _pop_size = 20
        int rand_i = rand_int();
        if (rand_i != 3 && rand_i != 6)
        { //using set. Not sure exactly what search it is. Probably a tree.
            if (tempplayers.find(rand_i) == tempplayers.end())
            {
                tempplayers.insert(rand_i);
                //players.push_back(rand_i);
                ++y;
            }
        }
    } while (y < _group_size - 1);
    // copy set into vector for comfortable use.
    std::copy(tempplayers.begin(), 
              tempplayers.end(), 
              std::back_inserter(players));
    //
    auto t2 = duration_cast<nanoseconds>(high_resolution_clock::now() - start).count();
    std::cout << "Time (ns) with set: " << t2 << std::endl;
    if (t2 > 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Set is " << t1/ t2 << " times faster"<< std::endl;
    }
}
```

A typical output is:

```
Time (ns) with vector: 373014100
Time (ns) with set: 9000800
Set is 41 times faster
```

NB: I'm running on Windows and my default tick resolution is horrible.

Comment: my result are different: [Time (ns) with vector: 174136500] [Time (ns) with set: 160125800] [Set is 1 times faster].  But if I set group_size to 100 000, Set is 6 times faster. Technically you are correct. I will mark your answer as correct. Thank you for the lessons.

Answer (score 0):

Better way, is to use a simple array instead of vector.
Since I know the size of the group I just create an array of size x, and add the values to it. To check if the values are already in the array I use a simple for loop.

What happens it that a vector takes time to allocate memory for the next number and an array no, he has already allocated memory for those numbers when I do this:

```
int array[4];
```

One test took me 96 seconds, after I changed to an array the same test took only 26 seconds.